# Ruby "include?" outputting false when element appears to be in array

Tags: ruby

I am writing a simple program to filter out stock quotes from a given string via a regex. I am not having a problem with the printed results in the array but when I attempt to use "include?" to output a bool of a specific printed result, I am receiving false.

This code demonstrates my exact issue:

http://ideone.com/JiQlA

I have shown the matches, the # of elements, and verified it is an array in the code but when I try to pull the specific printed element "A" using "include?" (line 10), it fails to output "true."

I would very much appreciate if someone would kindly explain my error here or how I would appropriately go about finding if a specific element is in the array. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`puts matches.map{|x| x.to_s}.include?("A")`

Comment: and to see what your error was, replace `puts matches` with `puts matches.inspect`

Comment: There's a shorter way: `matches.map(&:to_s).include?('A')`

Answer (score 8):

The elements in your Array are not Strings, they're MatchData which happen to print as Strings. Since String `"A"` is not equal to `#<MatchData "A" 1:nil>`, `include?` fails.

Answer (score 1):

Because `matches` is an array of `MatchData` objects, [as seen here](http://ideone.com/JPAoh). You need to convert the elements to strings first, so do that in your `map` call:

```
matches = s.to_enum(:scan, r).map { Regexp.last_match.to_s }
```